# Zapier Dynamic Custom Fields

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to offer custom fields from a platform as input fields I have done this in the past with another platform and with Zapiers older UI. It does not seem to be that simple now.

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Database',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  },
  params: {
    'ApiKey': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  }
};

return z.request(options).then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = response.json;

const col = results.DatabaseColumns.filter((item) => item.IsCustom).map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      id: item["ColumnName"],
    };
  });

  return col});
```

That is what I am trying to use for the Action. I am using this same does for a Trigger and it works there, but not as Dynamic Field Option along with other standard inputs.

Not sure if I need to tweak the code or if I can invoke the data that the Trigger would pull?

Here is the visual of the fields, but I need it to pull and offer the custom fields. This would be like favorite color, etc.

[Image of Zap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ9Fr.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this code:

```
// Configure a request to an endpoint of your api that
// returns custom field meta data for the authenticated
// user.  Don't forget to congigure authentication!

const options = {
  url: 'https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Database',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  },
  params: {
    'ApiKey': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  }
};


return z.request(options).then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = response.json;

  var col = results.DatabaseColumns.filter((item) => item.IsCustom).map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      key: item["ColumnName"],
      value: item["ColumnName"]
    };
  });

  //var col = col.filter(items => ['FirstName', 'LastName'].indexOf(items) >= 0 )
  for (var i = col.length; i--;) {
    if (col[i].key === 'FirstName' || col[i].key === 'LastName' ) {
        col.splice(i, 1);
    }
    }


  return col});
    
    
    /*
    return [ 
      {
        "key": "FirstName",
        "value":"First Name"
      },
      {
        "key": "LastName",
        "value": "Last Name"
      },
      {
        "key": "Test",
        "value": "Test 2"
      },
      */
```